# \hspace{amount} equal to \begin{quote} indentation

Tags: spacing

What amount of `\hspace` is equal to the amount `\begin{quote}` indents?

Below is the preamble in the document I am creating

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt,pdftex]{article} 
\usepackage[margin=.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumerate}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
```

Answer (score 4):

The standard `quote` environment uses `\leftmargin`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{quote}
This is a quote
\end{quote}
\hspace*{\leftmargin}And this is aligned

\end{document}
```

[image]